# Is it possible to create WAN-wide topic in Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

In the Hazelcast manual said that topics are cluster-wide. Also there is a description how to configure a WAN-replication for the map. However as far as I understand from the hazelcast-fullconfig.xml, topics are not backed with maps (like queues, for example). So I am interesting if it's possible to create WAN-wide topic in Hazelcast?

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current design, topic implementation is stand-alone , not backed with maps. And it is not possible to make it WAN-wide.